# Rendering hundreds of Views/Touchs (how to be performatic) in React-Native

Tags: react-native, performance, rendering, touchableopacity, multiple-views

If you have any experience rendering lot of views I'm glad to hear:

Im trying to render about hundreds of views in a single page.
More specifically i'm rendering a map of objects which has its own colors inside it.
It will be a grid of about 144x256 (i dont remind the actual scale now)

the amount of views to render slows down the page to an unusable state

So far Iv tried:

- Views
- TouchableOpacities
- reanimated components (for native like
  interaction)

Some steps i'm about to try yet are:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image (or a rn compatible library)
- canvas

Bellow is an example using reanimated component and views.
Even this simple grid is not fast enought, and its only 9x16

[image]

the code i'm using so far is a little bit complicated (because i'm structuring it for a big page)
Haha, i dont think its worth pasting it here but i'll:

```
const DEFAULTS={
  city:{
    GENERALDATA:{
      prefixes:generalDatas.city.prefixes,
    },
    indexes:mapIndexes,
    rows:[...Array(mapIndexes.y).keys()].map(row=>row=[...Array(mapIndexes.x).keys()]),
    array:{...[...Array(mapIndexes.y*mapIndexes.x)].map(blk=>blk={color:'#000'})}
  }, // 256x144   // {coords:[],prev:[],owner,usersData:{'users sent data like [type,houseNumber,50km/h]'}}
}
```

```
 const stateDatas = {
    anm:{
      anmText:{

      },
      bitMapIndexes:DEFAULTS.city.indexes,
      bitMap:DEFAULTS.city.array,
      bitMapRows:DEFAULTS.city.rows,
      bitMapKeys:Object.keys(DEFAULTS.city.array),
    }
  }

const renderMap=()=>{
    const renderBlock=(rowI,i,rowLength)=>{
      return(
        <Animated.View style={[{
          width:anmBitMapProps.value.resProportion.x,
          height:anmBitMapProps.value.resProportion.y,
          backgroundColor:'#262626',
          borderColor:'#191919',
          borderWidth:1,
          justifyContent:'center',
          alignItems:'center',
          // borderStyle:'solid'
        },anm.bitMap[(rowI*rowLength)+i]]}>
          <Text style={styles.softText}>1km</Text>
          <Text style={styles.softText}>chunk</Text>
        </Animated.View>
      )
    }

    const renderRow=(row,rowI,rowLength)=>{
      return(
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
          {row.map(i=>renderBlock(rowI,i,rowLength))}
        </View>
      )
    }

    const anmBitMapArray = stateDatas.anm.bitMapRows.map((row,rowI)=>renderRow(row,rowI,row.length))

    return(
      <View style={{position:'absolute',width:'100%',height:'100%',backgroundColor:'#121212'}}>
        {anmBitMapArray}
      </View>
    )
```

I truncated it a bit, might be missing some parts

Comment: Can you share code of each chunk and the code snippet where you are mapping over the elements?

Comment: Did it, but i dont think its worth reading

Comment: Do you have a recording of the performance now? Or what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Built-in Animated or Reanimated2?

Comment: Reanimated 2
I can record the screen to show in 9x16 and 256x144 if needed

Answer (score 1):

It would require a lot more code snippet and analysis to reach to a snappy UI state. Anyway, I'll try to give some pointers based on the above snippet.

1. Avoid using inline css. Use css classes are target the relevant elements.
2. We don't have to initialize same objects again.
3. {
   width:anmBitMapProps.value.resProportion.x,
   height:anmBitMapProps.value.resProportion.y,
   backgroundColor:'#262626',
   borderColor:'#191919',
   borderWidth:1,
   justifyContent:'center',
   alignItems:'center',
   // borderStyle:'solid'
   }

This object is same for all child elements. So we can initalize it next to `stateDatas` and reuse it.

4. Another reusable piece of code is:

```
    <Text style={styles.softText}>1km</Text>
    <Text style={styles.softText}>chunk</Text>
```

This can be taken out in a separate component and wrapped inside a `React.memo`. Since this is same for all the components so no need to re-create it